# Forward or redirect email with attachments using Apple Mail to another email address

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, exchange, mail-rules

I'm on MacOS Sierra. I'm using Apple Mail with Exchange Server. I want to set a rule that when an email is received from a specific sender, then redirect the email to another email address. I'm trying to use the "forward to" or the "redirect to" options but both only forward the email without the attachment.

Can anyone please tell me how to set the rule to send the email along with its attachment to the specified email?

Answer (score 1):

Why not set up a server side rule using an exchange client? Webmail or outlook might work well and be included.

Comment: I did try to set it up, when I go to Edit Rules, on the left hand side, I see under "Server Rules", my account, I click it and add a new rule to it for forwarding or redirecting, and it doesn't work. All other rules like Move to Folder etc. work. Below the "Server Rules" is "Client Rules" under which I see "Exchange", "POP", etc. I do not want to set Client Rules coz they are applied only when I am logged into the outlook app. Can you please provide a fix??

Comment: See my other question for more details: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300905/outlook-for-mac-redirect-to-rule-not-working